# Can't get jQuery cycle plugin to work Why?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I have loaded both the cycle2 and the cycle2 carousel plugin and i am trying to get the following simple demo to work:

HTML:

```
<div class="slideshow" 
            class="slideshow" 
            data-cycle-fx=carousel
            data-cycle-timeout=1000 >

        <img src="img/gallery/g1.jpg" alt="featured development project">
        <img src="img/gallery/g2.jpg" alt="featured development project">
        <img src="img/gallery/g3.jpg" alt="featured development project">
        <img src="img/gallery/g1.jpg" alt="featured development project">

</div>  

<a href="#" id="g-next">next</a>
<br><br><a href="#" id="g-prev">prev</a>
```

I have the following scripts loaded:

```
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery.cycle2.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery.cycle2.carousel.js"></script>
```

But my demo would still now work , WHY ? i have followed exactly whats on the demo page **[HERE](http://malsup.com/jquery/cycle2/demo/carousel.php)** , but still can't get the cycle plugin to work.

**[FIDDLE HERE](https://jsfiddle.net/efq5fw2s/)**

Answer (score 1):

You have to initialize the plugin. I've updated your fiddle with the init and it looks like this: https://jsfiddle.net/maffelu/efq5fw2s/1/

At the end of the javascript code you'll see the initialization:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".slideshow").cycle();
});
```